# How do rails extract an id from an instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm reading ["Rails Routing from the Outside In" on RailsGuides.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

In Section 1.2, it says

```
<%= link_to 'Patient Record', patient_path(@patient) %>
```

will generate the path /patients/17.

What I'd like to know is how rails extract the id from the instance variable.
I've been trying to find the corresponding line of the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails) but can't find.

Comment: With an instance variable containing an active record, you can just call it directly: `@patient.id` the same way you'd get to any element of the record, such as `@patient.first_name` -- Is that what you're looking for or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID comes from calling `#to_param` on the object. Here is a little documentation about it, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#to-param

Comment: Thank you! This is what I wanted to know. Also, I'd like to take this opportunity to thank everyone for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

It calls a `to_param` method which by default will produce the ID. You can override it to produce nice URLs like this

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{title}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

method responsible is to_param. link to line on 
[github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04cda1848cb847c2bdad0bfc12160dc8d5547775/activerecord/lib/active_record/integration.rb#L38)